# Call functions in php file along with the code

Tags: php

I have following php file when i run it xxxx/api.php nothing is shown in browser. the echo doesn't show up either. What is wrong.

```
  <?php 
            try {
                    echo "asdf";
                    $conn = GetDBConnection();          
                    $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(shuffel.clientid) as total_users FROM shuffel');
                    $statement->execute();
                    $total = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    $total =$total['total_users'];
                    echo 1;
                    //$tokens = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

                    if($total >= 2)
                    {
                        $result=$total/2;
                        $length =round($result);
                        if ($length > 10)
                            $length = 10;

                        for($i=0 ; $i < $length ; $i++) 
                        {
                            $statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM shuffel ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2');
                            $statement->execute();
                            $row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            $my_arary = array();

                            print_r($my_arary[]);
                            echo $firstClient   = $my_arary[0];   
                            echo $firstClientId = $firstClient->clientId;
                            echo $firstFilters  = $firstClient->filters;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                        throw $e;
                }       

        function GetDBConnection() 
        {
            $conn = null;
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName', 'admin', 'password');
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                throw $e;
            }

            return $conn;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: What do your logs say is wrong?

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting`. You likely have a parse error.

Comment: I'm unsure what `print_r($my_arary[]);` is supposed to be doing here, do you mean `print_r($my_arary);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a parse error here:

```
print_r($my_arary[]); // "Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading"
```

You also start with an empty array...

```
$my_arary = array();
```

And then try to treat a non-existant array value as an object...

```
echo $firstClient   = $my_arary[0];   
echo $firstClientId = $firstClient->clientId; // "Trying to get property of non-object"
```

Also, up top you are using `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` for your fetch, and then immediately using array notation rather than object.

Turn on `error_reporting` so you can see what's going on.

Comment: $conn = GetDBConnection();   is this correctly used?

Comment: I think so, appears to be.

Answer (score 0):

"Call functions in php file along with the code"  It looks like you may have larger issues, since echo is not displayed either.

Check you webserver error logs.  You might also try a very basic php script for debugging.  Maybe just the echo or phpinfo();